# Ошибка компиляции illegal start of expression

Tags: java

Есть код который получая строку должен полиндром это или нет. Вроде всё правельно, НО выдаёт ошибку: Palindromes.java:27: error: illegal start of expression
Если закоментировать If - Else то ошибки нет. Но эта проверка нужна. Подскажите что не так.
Спасибо.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Palindromes
 * A task 50
 **/

public class Palindromes{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String scan = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        scan = scan.toLowerCase();
        
        String normalString = removal(scan);
        String changeling = reverseString(normalString);
        
        System.out.println(changeling);
        System.out.print(normalString);
        
        if(normalString == changeling){
            System.out.print("Y");
            }// if
        else{System.out.print("N");
            
        
        }// main class
        
    static String removal(String string){
        string = string.replaceAll(" ","");
        string = string.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","");
        
        return string;
        }// Removal
        
    static String reverseString(String str) {
        return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
        }// reverseString 

}//polindromes class
```

Comment: покажите, где именно находится Ваша 27 строка. В районе того закомментированного if?

Comment: после `System.out.print("N");` надо закрыть `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает закрывающей фигурной скобки для метода `main` либо для else

потому что

```
if(normalString == changeling){
        System.out.print("Y");
        }// if
    else{System.out.print("N");
```

тут очевидно нет фигурной скобки `}`

Comment: Вот это позорище((( Блинн!!! Спасибо Вам всем

Comment: Галочку рядом с ответом - тык))

Comment: А у меня там новый вопрос))) Глянешь?